# Accessing higher UDP ports in Windows UWP

Tags: uwp, udp, port, datagram, udpclient

I have an application that was originally written for Win8 Modern. I use UDP to communicate with external hardware through port 54372.

I ported it to Android and iOS and now want to re-port it back to UWP.
When I tried to access the port in my UWP App, I get an unknown error. I tried both the original DatagramSocket method from my Modern App, and the System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient method from the Android and iOS Apps.

I then tried running the DatagramSocket sample from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/datagramsocket/

If I use their default service, no problems. If I change it to 54372, I get the error message:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'An attempt was made to
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

It appears now that the code is OK, just that MS now imposes restrictions on what ports I can use.

What changes do I need to apply to the permissions to allow my App to access this port? The hardware is a commercial product that has been in the field for the past 9 years, so changing the port is not an option.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Which port that used in your server client?

Comment: I am using port 54372. If you load the sample App from Microsoft, it works for low numbered ports but fails if you try to use higher number ports. Modern Apps (Win 8), and those for Android and iOS do not have this problem.

Comment: Further investigation has shown that ports in the range 54349-54448 all have the same problem. What is special about this range of 100 ports?

Comment: May this range of 100 ports(54349-54448) were occupied by system.

Comment: If so, it is a recent change. (last few months??) It is in the range that is supposed to be "Dynamic and/or Private" according to IANA. It has been working for the past 9 years. No scans show it as being in use. I can find no reference to them in MS docs.

Comment: I tried adding the port to the firewall, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I tested with official cod sample but I could not reproduce your issue could you share more info about your test environment.

Comment: standard Lenovo laptop running Windows 10 Pro, Build 1862.19h1_release 190318-1202 ||  VS2019 Community 16.4.3 || VS2013 Ultimate 12.0.40629.00 Update 5. The latter was used to develop the Win8 App. No changes in system or software other than MS updates since last worked on Win8 app 7/2018.

Comment: Nico, when you ran the code sample, did you enter 54372 into the service box and select "Listen"? That is when the exception is thrown. It would be nice if the OS told you the reason the access is denied. If it is due to the OS or other software changes, I would like to be able to tell the customer when they call in with a problem that they have to "Turn off the XYZ app before running the program."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It appears to be Apple's Bonjour service. Rather that just "taking" the single UDP port that it needed, it allocated a block of 100. Just my luck that my default port was in the middle of this block. After stopping Bonjour, everything works fine. Restarting Bonjour caused it to pick a different block, so it is no longer interfering. It forced us to modify the various versions of the App to allow for alternate UDP ports and post a firmware update to change the ports in case any customers ran into this problem in the future. Again, it would have been nice if the OS had told me what the problem was, not just "unauthorized access"